# Mongoose const castError = new CastError();

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I seem to be getting this error:

```
C:\...\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4638
  const castError = new CastError();
                    ^

CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "undefined" (type string) at path "_id" for model "cProd"
    at model.Query.exec (C:\...\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4638:21)
    at model.Query.Query.then (C:\...\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4737:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  messageFormat: undefined,
  stringValue: '"undefined"',
  kind: 'ObjectId',
  value: 'undefined',
  path: '_id',
  reason: BSONTypeError: Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters
      at new BSONTypeError (C:\...\node_modules\bson\lib\error.js:41:28)
      at new ObjectId (C:\...\node_modules\bson\lib\objectid.js:65:23)
      at castObjectId (C:\...\node_modules\mongoose\lib\cast\objectid.js:24:12)
      at ObjectId.cast (C:\...\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\objectid.js:247:12)
      at ObjectId.SchemaType.applySetters (C:\...\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1180:12)
      at ObjectId.SchemaType._castForQuery (C:\...\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1615:15)
      at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQuery (C:\...\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1605:15)
      at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQueryWrapper (C:\...\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1582:20)
      at cast (C:\...\node_modules\mongoose\lib\cast.js:341:32)
      at model.Query.Query.cast (C:\...\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:5073:12),
  valueType: 'string'
}
```

for this code:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cProd = require('./models/cProd');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:#/database', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
});

const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', () => {
  console.log('Database connected');
});

const app = express();

// app.engine('ejs', ejsMate)
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))

// Parsing request.body

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('main')
});

app.get('/cProds', async (req, res) => {
    const cProds = await cProd.find({});
    res.render('cProds/index', {cProds})
});

app.get('/cProds/create', (req, res) => {
    res.render('cProds/create');
})

app.post('/cProds', async (req, res) => {
    const conProd = new cProd(req.body.cProd);
    await conProd.save();
    res.redirect(`/cProds/${cProd._id}`)
});

app.get('/cProds/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const conProd = await cProd.findById(req.params.id)
    res.render('cProds/show', {conProd})
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Serving on port #')
})
```

The app.post above seems to work when I do a simple res.send(req.body), but I get this error if I finish the code.

Dumb question, is it possibly due to not installing UUID? I don't believe I have yet.

Please help - complete beginner here who has exhausted research and figuring this out.

UPDATE: Schema and Model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const opts = {toJSON:{virtuals:true}};

const CProdSchema = new Schema({
    product_name: String,
    type: String,
    description: String
}, opts);

CProdSchema.virtual('properties.popUpMarkup').get(function() {
    return `
    <strong><a href="/campgrounds/${this._id}">${this.product_name}</a></strong>
    <p>${this.description.substring(0,20)}...</p>`
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('cProd', CProdSchema)
```

Comment: It's not due to UUID, mongo uses it's own ID system, they are called [BSON ObjectIds](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/). Somehow your post body contains an id which is the string "undefined". Can you show us the contents of `req.body`?

Comment: Hi @caffeinated.tech, thank you kindly for your response. This is it:

{"cProd":{"prodName":"New","type":"New"}}

Comment: OK, that body is fine, so there must be another problem. Can you edit the question and add the code for the cProd schema and model?

Comment: Hi @caffeinated.tech, sorry for the delay in this, had a demanding couple of days at work. Please see the edits as requested - once again, truly appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I think I was blind.

Your problem method:

```
app.post('/cProds', async (req, res) => {
    const conProd = new cProd(req.body.cProd);
    await conProd.save();
    res.redirect(`/cProds/${cProd._id}`)
});
```

You want to send the user to the url for the newly created cProd. But `cProd` is the model name, while `conProd` is the new document created.
Simply change the last line:

```
    res.redirect(`/cProds/${conProd._id}`)
```

To avoid the confusion in future, I recommend sticking to capitalized first letter of models. I'm making a guess at the name, so for example:

```
const CampgroundProduct = require('./models/cProd');
```

And any instances (documents) of this model can be called `campgroundProduct` or simply `product`.

As to how that specific error code happened, I'm guessing that `model._id` references the creator for that type of field, which would be `mongoose.Types.ObjectId()`

Comment: Hi @caffeinated.tech! Thanks so much - you're amazing. It's fixed now! Quick question though, I didn't use conProd initially but I used cProd instead for where it is right now previously.

app.post('/cProds', async (req, res) => {
    const cProd= new cProd(req.body.cProd);
    await cProd.save();
    res.redirect(`/cProds/${cProd._id}`)
});

This would not work either would it?

Comment: @MortalDanger No, that would have raised an error as you defined `const cProd` at the top of your file. A constant cannot be reassigned. If you had replaced `const` with `let` you would have overwritten the `cProd` model meaning only the first request would have worked and all others would have failed

Comment: Aah okay - the above is understood. Truly appreciate your help! Thanks so much!